# Error undefined is not a function when change text

Tags: react-redux, react-native

I am trying the increment and decrement tutorial . When I type a number at the textinput, this value is to be reflected to the  this text given. But I am getting error. The error says

```
undefined is not a function(evaluating 'this.props.counterSet(count)')
```

These are the codes that I have tried. Can anybody tell me where I have done the mistake.

Thank You

```
- App
  -Actions
    -ActionTypes.js
    -CounterAction.js
  -Reducers
    -counterReducer.js
  app.js
```

### counterReducer.js

```
export default (state = 0, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET':
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

### counterAction.js

```
export const counterSet = (receivedNumber) => {
    return {
        type: 'SET',
        payload: receivedNumber
    }
}
```

### ActionTypes.js

```
export * from './CounterAction';
```

### app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { counterSet } from './Actions/ActionTypes';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: 0
        };
        this.onChangeText = this.onChangeText.bind(this);
    }

    onChangeText(number) {
        let count = parseInt(number);
        // alert("inside", count);
        this.props.counterSet(count);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                    style={{ width: 40, height: 40, borderWidth: 1 }}
                    onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
                    value={this.props.count.toString()}
                />
                <View style={styles.countViewStyle}>
                    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                        {this.props.count}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        count: state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { counterIncrement, counterDecrement, counterClear, counterSet })(App);
```

Comment: where are you passing the counterSet function from

Comment: function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        count: state
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { counterSet })(App);

Comment: A complete definition of App class would be helpful in debugging

Comment: How are you importing `counterSet` function in `App.js` ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the import from

`export * from './CounterAction';`

to

`export { counterSet } from './CounterAction;`

Hope this will help!